# How to implement load pattern in Jmeter load test script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to develop a performance load test of a ***Web Server user interactions*** by replicating the real life **load pattern**, but I am not sure how to do it in Jmeter.

**Here is my requirements:**

1. To implement a 1-hour load test by replicating 24-hour period load pattern 
   (as listed below)
2. To simulate the real life load pattern, I have to continuously start
   and stop user sessions (threads)
3. for example, I have to start the load test script with 20 virtual
   users (threads) logged in (representing 00:00:00 AM load) and 10 virtual users logged out
4. then, continue until 03:00:00 AM when 5 more users will be logged out
5. the pattern will proceed with logging in and logging out as indicated in the 
   table below

**Challenges:**
I am not taking the straight forwardly the highest number of users (e.g. 200 users logged in at 11:00:00 AM) as my max. virtual users (or threads) to ramp, rather the threads will be started and dropped by replicating the pattern below.

**Load pattern of user interactions for a typical 24 hour period:**
[image]

Comment: You should provide more information and include whatever code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is going for [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can ramp up and ramp down virtual users in a very flexible manner

[image: JMeter Ultimate Thread Group[2]]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of Custom Thread Groups bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Ultimate Thread Group]

Check out [How to Use the Ultimate Thread Group, the RegEx Extractor and the JSON Path Extractor in Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-ultimate-thread-group-regex-extractor-and-json-path-extractor-apache-jmeter) for comprehensive information on installation and using of the Ultimate Thread Group

Comment: Thanks Dmirti T for your solution. I'll definitely install Ultimate Thread Group plugin and try your solution.